# Как отобразить и сохранить атрибуты через Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ситуация такая: стоят плагины WooCommerce Advanced Bulk Edit и All Import. Выбираю список товаров, далее редактирую его, присваивая некий атрибут, процесс сохранения идет, в списке атрибутов товаров промышленного назначения, но, если открыть карточку товара - их там нет. Вообще. Затем вы выбираете этот же атрибут в расширенном массовом редактировании WooCommerce и уже в месте атрибута пустота, но товар остается в списке атрибутов и загружается. Но он просто не сохраняется и в перспективе не выводится в Характеристики. Если ранее товар был загружен через All import, то он остается в атрибутах, но они не сохраняются в карточке товара, загружаются в WooCommerce Advanced Bulk Edit, но при пересохранении там, перестают быть переменными.